# Handling dbnull values correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, error-handling, dbnull

I have written code which retrieves an email address from an access db when the username is the same as the user who has logged into my program. I wish to display the email address value in a textbox named `Email`

```
Dim x

If ConnectionDb.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then ConnectionDb.Open()
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = ConnectionDb.CreateCommand
cmd.CommandText = " SELECT ID, EmailAddress, TelephoneNo FROM tblContacts WHERE ID='" & NameVariable & "'"
x = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While x.Read()
    If x("EmailAddress").IsDBNull(0) Then
        Return
    Else
        Email.Text = x.GetString(0)
    End If
 . . . .
```

However, I receive the following error when the program is run as some users do not have a value for EmailAddress:

> System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'IsDBNull' on type 'DBNull' not found.' - line 7

I wish to also add functionality for the `TelephoneNo` value to also be displayed in a textbox on the form.
How can I successfully check for null values without the program running into an error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're not supposed to delete questions that have answers. they will be restored. What you should do, accept the answer if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on you options, `Dim x` can be a different thing. If option `infer` is `On`, this is a `reader` here

```
Dim x = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

But in your case this is `object` because with `option infer` you need to declare and assign on same line. you need to do `Dim x as OleDbDataReader`. This way you will see intellisence error on `IsDBNull`. you really run into late binding error here

you should do this

```
If DbNull.Value.Equals(x("EmailAddress")) Then
```

This will solve your issue. But you have more issues. Ok, if you select single row/single value, just use `ExecuteScalar`.

Or, at least do

```
If x.Read() AndAlso Not DbNull.Value.Equals(x("EmailAddress")) Then
    Email.Text = x("EmailAddress").ToString()
End If
```

Comment: If an empty string is "equivalent" to a DB null in the software requirements, it may be more readable to use `AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x("EmailAddress"))` or even `AndAlso x.("EmailAddress").ToString.Length > 0`. These will also account for an empty string coming from the database.

Comment: @HardCode I hope you mean to use `IsNullOrEmpty` after the `DBnull` check in `IF`. Because you can't use `IsNullOrEmpty` instead of `DBNull`. But it is also depend on DB. For example, Oracle does not have a concept of empty string - only null or value. In this context, really, what you could add is `Trim()` during assignment. Text box is never `null`. But if someone stores empty spaces into DB, this is the start of the problem. All data saved should be trimmed. Could you see a scenario where you have `value1` in txt, push the button and `value1` remains if no record found? you first empty it

Comment: ugh, that should have been `String.IsNullOrEmpty(x("EmailAddress").ToString)`

Comment: `If x.Read() AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x("EmailAddress").ToString) Then` You know, after re-pasting the original line, I'm starting to doubt my thought on "may be more readable" for this one.

Comment: In my VB.NET code, I have code for a DataRow, from a DataTable, loaded via a DataAdapter, that will consider a DB null value in `dr("MyField").ToString` as an empty string. It converts the null to an empty string.

Comment: @HardCode Actually, you're correct. `DbNull.Value.ToString()` would return `string.empty`. I messed up by adding only `DbNull`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (but tricky solution) is perhaps following

```
While x.Read()
    Email.Text = x("EmailAddress") & ""
    ...
```

If `x("EmailAddress")` is DBNUll, `Email.Text` contains an empty string (= "").

In all other cases, it contains `EmailAddress` column value.